# Proving $AB = BA$ when $A$ is the Identity matrix times a scalar.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Let $A \in R^{n \times n}$

Show that if $A =\alpha I$ for some $\alpha \in R$, then for all $B \in R^{n \times n}$ we have $AB = BA$

I proved this by:

$$AB = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \cdots & \alpha\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} b_{11} & \cdots & b_{1n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ b_{n1} & \cdots & b_{nn}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha b_{11} & \cdots & \alpha b_{1n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \alpha b_{n1} & \cdots & \alpha b_{nn}\end{bmatrix}$$

$$BA = \begin{bmatrix} b_{11} & \cdots & b_{1n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ b_{n1} & \cdots & b_{nn}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \cdots & \alpha\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha b_{11} & \cdots & \alpha b_{1n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \alpha b_{n1} & \cdots & \alpha b_{nn}\end{bmatrix}$$

$$AB = BA$$

How do I prove the opposite case?
Show that if $B \in R^{n \times n}$ we have $AB = BA$, then there exists a $\alpha \in R$ such that $A = \alpha I$?

Comment: The opposite is not true. You could have for example $A=B$.

Comment: Can you please explain that?

Comment: There might be some confusion as you stated the opposite case incorrectly. If $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $AB=BA$, then there is no guarantee that $A$ is a scalar matrix as Jaap Scherphuis noted.

The opposite direction of your first statement is the following: If $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a matrix such that for all $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ we have $AB=BA$. In that case the hint given in the link provided by J.E. Pin is useful to consider.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin while it's a possible duplicate- the difference between the level of people who are searching for each of the questions is *enormous*, imo.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite is false. To see this consider two linear transformations $A$ and $B$ with $A$ the orthogonal projection onto the span of $(0,1)$ and B the orthogonal projection onto the span of $(1,0)$. Then $AB=BA=O$ but neither $A$ or $B$ is of the form $\alpha I$.